# How to change icon of application in program files?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am developing wpf application. I have created the setup project. It runs successfully and install the application. The application will be shown in Start -> All Programs. Now when the application name appears in the All Programs list, it appears with default icon on left side of application name. I want to change this default icon. For example IE in All Programs has the symbol(e) on left side of it. How to change icon of application in All Programs ? Can you please provide me any solution for the above issue

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672537/setting-icon-for-wpf-application-vs-08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may setup the Icon for the application before creating the installer. You can go to the project properties under application tab, you can set the default Icon for the application.

[image]

*If you want to modify the icon for installed application, then it is going to be same as for rest of the shortcuts for other applications. Right click on the shortcut, select properties and Change Icon.*

EDIT: You may see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956621/how-to-add-icon-to-wpf-application-desktop-shortcut) if want to add a desktop shortcut to the WPF application.

Comment: I have already done this. The icon shows in the title bar of the application once the application gets launched. I dont want this. For e.g I have installed application. It now appears with name 'Test' in All Programs. 'Test' also has the icon on left side of it. I want to change this icon

Comment: Yes I want this - If you want to modify the icon for installed application, then it is going to be same as for rest of the shortcuts for other applications. Right click on the shortcut, select properties and Change Icon.

Comment: But I dont want to manually change the icon of installed application. I want to do this in setup project. So once it get installed, the icon will be shown

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956621/how-to-add-icon-to-wpf-application-desktop-shortcut

Comment: Yes Habib. I got my answer from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956621/how-to-add-icon-to-wpf-application-desktop-shortcut. Thanks

Comment: I found this link useful to add checkbox in installed wizard to create shortcut on desktop http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11758/Conditional-Install-of-Desktop-and-Quick-Launch-Sh#Setup