# Set window icon does not apply in task bar when app has windows shortcut

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, window, taskbar

I have observed strange case. I build WPF app and I tried to change Window.Icon dynamically during runtime so that the icon is being changed in task bar (not only in window title). I change it programmatically by assigning ImageSource to Window.Icon property.

Normally it works as I expect, but when I create shortcut to this app under Windows (7) the icon is not being changed in the task bar and instead of this I see icon which comes from that shortcut. (in window title the icon changes independently)

Can anybody help to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also set the Icon in the project properties, in the application tab under the resources group.

I Don't know if this applies to the shortcut, but you could try that.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can set it in project Properties but it not resolves my case.

Comment: and how about this suggestion?   <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956621/how-to-add-icon-to-wpf-application-desktop-shortcut>

Comment: Unfortunately that question relates to setting an icon in shortcut. It is about installation of the app (during setup process).